# Making multiple plots in R dependent on two different categorical variables

Tags: r, graph, plot

I'm new to R and I'm trying to generate in RStudio multiple bar plots in a single graph by using a dataset with more than 1000 observations of several variables. Below is an fragment of the dataset:

```
Municipality    Production  Type
Atima           690         Reverification
Atima           120         Reverification
Atima           220         Reverification
Comayagua       153         Initial
Comayagua       193         Initial
Comayagua       138         Initial
Comayagua       307         Reverification
Copán           179         Initial
Copán           100         Initial
Copán           236         Reverification
Copán           141         Reverification
Danlí            56         Reverification
...
```

The dataset's structure is

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1543 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Municipality    : chr  "Atima" "Atima" "Atima" "Comayagua" ...
$ Production      : num  98 690 153 307 179 ...
$ Type            : chr  "Reverification" "Reverification" "Reverification" "Initial" ...
```

What I would like to come up with is a barplot displaying a pair of bars (1 pair per municipality), a bar showing how much production a municipality had in "Initial" and another bar showing how much in "Reverification".

I've tried with various commands, such as barplot, barchart and ggplot, but so far without success.

Should I split the Type variable into 2, 1 for each category? I've also tried to plot it only for production depending on the type, and received the following message:

```
barplot(table(dataset$Production[dataset$Type=="Initial"]), names.arg = Municipality)
Error in barplot.default(dataset$Production[dataset$Type=="Initial"]), names.arg = 
Municipality, : incorrect number of names
```

I'm working in Rstudio Version 0.99.441, in Windows 7.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df_s <- 
    as.data.table(df)[ , .("Production_Sum" = sum(Production)),
                      by = .(Municipality, Type)]

ggplot(df_s, aes( x = Municipality, y = Production_Sum, fill = Type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

I am using the following data (which you specified in your OP):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Municipality    Production  Type
Atima           690         Reverification
Atima           120         Reverification
Atima           220         Reverification
Comayagua       153         Initial
Comayagua       193         Initial
Comayagua       138         Initial
Comayagua       307         Reverification
Copán           179         Initial
Copán           100         Initial
Copán           236         Reverification
Copán           141         Reverification
Danlí            56         Reverification
")
```

Comment: Hi grrgrrbla, i'm getting this error message: 

    Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function

What is my mistake? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the data.frame you should be using should be named df, you input it at the beginning of the ggplot-function-call so `ggplot(data = df,.....)` , so instead of df put there whatever your data.frame is called, I am guessing yours is not called df but something different, I edited the question to include the data I used

Comment: this requires more work, reshaping and summarising the data... I edited my post, please accept the answer by clicking the tick-mark and upvote it by clicking the up-arrow

Comment: thats okay, happy it worked, I would check out a good tutorial on ggplot2, will help you forever